Required Field validation firing on field hidden by Dynamic Action Apex
I have an application in which I hide some fields (Date Picker) based on user input with a dynamic action. Some of these fields are marked as "Required Fields" (obviously, if they are not hidden by the dynamic action) and have associated validation firing on submit.
How do I override the validation being fired if the field was hidden by the dynamic action?

The 'Value Required' property on an item causes both a client-side as well as a server-side validation. So even if you are able to manage to bypass the validation client-side, it won't help you. For your scenario, I'm afraid you will need a custom validation, taking into account the logic which you already have for the condition as to hide the field.

A validation is just a server side rule for a page item value. When an apex page is submitted, the server side processes (validations/computations/processes and branches) are not aware of any actions that affected the DOM after the page was rendered. So the server does not know if a page item is hidden or shown or disabled.
This is definitely not a bug for the following reason: a show/hide dynamic action is just a jquery call. So any user with basic javascript knowledge can hide an item on the page from the browser dev console. It's even documented :) If the validation would not fire on a hidden item, that would be a security risk.
Solution is, as mentioned in the comments, to add a condition to the validation to not fire with similar logic as the dynamic action. That way, if someone hides the item via javascript via the browser dev console, the validation will still fire as expected. When the DA hides the item, it will not.
